# Having trouble posting information from a html form to php script. (Undefined index)

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm working on an app for PHP class where we have to create an app to order pizza online. I'm stuck on an html form that is not posting on the script and I can't get it to work. I'm getting the following error and I don't know how to fix it.

I'm working on an app for PHP class where we have to create an app to order pizza online. I'm stuck on an html form that is not posting on the script and I can't get it to work. I'm getting the following error and I don't know how to fix it.  [Undefined index error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU6rW.png)

HTML index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>HTech Pizza Online Order</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="receipt.php" method="POST">
      <h2>HTech Pizzeria Online Order</h2>
      <fieldset>
          <legend><b>Customer Information</b></legend>
          Name: <input type="text" require id="customer" name="customer"
          placeholder="Enter Your Name..."><br>
          Phone Number: <input type="text" require id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber"
          placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number..."><br>
          Address: <input type="text" require id="address" name="address"
          placeholder="Enter Your Address..."><br>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div> 
  <form action="receipt.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
      <legend><b>Order Customization</b></legend>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <b>Size : </b><br><br>

        <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="size" value="Large"><label for="radio3"><span><span></span></span>Large: $10.00</label> <br>

        <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="size" value="Medium"><label for="radio2"><span><span></span></span>Medium: $8.00</label> <br>

        <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="size" value="Small" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span>Personal: $6.00</label> 
        <br>
        <br>

        <b>Crust : </b><br><br>

        <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="crust" value="traditional" checked="checked"><label for="radio4"><span><span></span></span>Traditional: $2.00</label><br>

        <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="crust" value="welldone"><label for="radio5"><span><span></span></span>Well Done: $2.00</label><br>

        <input id="radio6" type="radio" name="crust" value="thin"><label for="radio6"><span><span></span></span>Thin: $2.00</label><br><br>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox"><b>Toppings:</b><br><br>
        <div>  
          <input id="toppingBox1" type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Pepperoni"><label for="toppingBox1"><span></span>Pepperoni</label> 
        </div>
        <div> 
          <input id="toppingBox2" type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Bacon"><label for="toppingBox2"><span></span>Bacon</label>
        </div>

        <div>
          <input id="toppingBox3" type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Chicken"><label for="toppingBox3"><span></span>Chicken</label>
        </div>

        <div>
          <input id="toppingBox4" type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Sausage"><label for="toppingBox4"><span></span>Sausage</label>
        </div>

        <div>
          <input id="toppingBox5" type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Ham"><label for="toppingBox5"><span></span>Ham</label> 
        </div>

        <div>
          <input id="toppingBox6" type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="BlackOlives"><label for="toppingBox6"><span></span>Black Olives</label> 
        </div> 

        <div>
          <input id="toppingBox7" type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Parmesan"><label for="toppingBox7"><span></span>Parmesan</label>
        </div>

        <div>
          <input id="toppingBox8" type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="Pineapple"><label for="toppingBox8"><span></span>Pineapple</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>

      <div class="checkbox"><b>Student Discount: 
        </b><br><br>

        <input id="radio7" type="radio" name="studentBol" value="student"><label for="radio7"><span><span></span></span> Student</label> <br>

        <input id="radio8" type="radio"   name="studentBol" value="nonStudent"><label   for="radio8"><span><span></span></span>Non - Student</label><br>
        <br><hr><br>

        <b>Delivery or Pickup:</b> <br><br>

        <input id="radio9" type="radio" name="modePickup" value="Delivery"><label for="radio9"><span><span></span>
        </span>Delivery</label><br>

        <input id="radio0" type="radio" name="modePickup" value="Pickup"><label for="radio0"><span><span></span></span>Store Pickup</label><br>
        <br>


        <b>Boxes Of Pizza:</b><br><br>
        <div class="custom-select">
          <label>
            <select name="noOfPizza">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>

      Additional Instructions:<br><br>
      <label>
        <textarea name="addInstructions" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
      </label>
      <br>
      <br>

      <input class="btn btn1" type="submit" name="order" value="Order Now">

    </fieldset>
    <br>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Script

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['order'])) {

  // Check for pizza size 

  switch ($_POST['size']) {

    case "Small":
      $pizzaSizePrice = 6.00;
      break;

    case "Medium":
      $pizzaSizePrice = 8.00;
      break;

    case "Large":
      $pizzaSizePrice = 10.00;
      break;
  }

  // Checking Student Qualification

  if ($_POST['studentBol'] == "student") {
    $studentBol = true;
  } else {
    $studentBol = false;
  }

  // Toppings

  $toppingArray = $_POST['toppings'];

  if (count($toppingArray) == 1) {
    $toppingAmount = 0.00;
  } else {

    // First topping free, added toppings an extra $1

    $toppingAmount = count($toppingArray) - 1;
  }

  // Pickup

  if ($_POST['modePickup'] == "Delivery") {
    $modePickup = 5.00;
  } else {
    $modePickup = 0.00;
  }

  $crustType = 2.00;

  $numberOfPizza = $_POST['noOfPizza'];
  $instructions = $_POST['addInstructions'];

  // Calculating Amount

  $netAmount = $crustType + $pizzaSizePrice + $toppingAmount;

  $netAmount = $netAmount * $numberOfPizza;

  // Adding Delivery Fee

  $netAmount = $netAmount + $modePickup;

  if ($studentBol) {
    $studentDiscount = $netAmount * 10 / 100;

    // Applying the student discount 

    $netAmount = $netAmount - $studentDiscount;

    $studentDiscount = number_format($studentDiscount, 2, '.', '');
  }

  // adding tax

  $salesTax = $netAmount * 10 / 100;
  $salesTax = number_format($salesTax, 2, '.', '');

  $total = $salesTax + $netAmount;
  $total = number_format($total, 2, '.', '');
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Order Confirmation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Order Confirmation</h2>

  <hr>

  <h3>Customer Information:</h3>

  <h3>First Name:</h3><?php echo $_POST['customer']; ?>
  <h3>Phone Number:</h3><?php echo $_POST['phoneNumber']; ?>
  <h3>Address:</h3><?php echo $_POST['address']; ?>

  <hr>

  <h3>Size: </h3><?php echo $_POST['size'] . " $" . $pizzaSizePrice; ?>

  <h3>Crust Type: </h3><?php echo $_POST['crust'] . " $2"; ?>

  <h3>Toppings: </h3>
  <?php
  if (count($toppingArray) == 1) {

    foreach ($toppingArray as $topping) {
      echo $topping . " Free<br>";
    }
  } else {
    foreach ($toppingArray as $topping) {
      // First topping free

      if ($topping == "Peperroni") {
        echo $topping . " Free<br>";
      } else {
        echo $topping . " $1<br>";
      }
    }
  }
  ?>


  <h3>Pizza's Ordered: </h3><?php echo $numberOfPizza; ?>

  <h3>Additional Instructions:</h3> <?php echo $_POST['addInstructions']; ?>

  <br>
  <hr>

  <h3>Delivery or Pickup: </h3><?php echo $_POST['modePickup'] . " $" . $modePickup; ?>

  <!-- Check Student Discount -->
  <?php
  if ($studentBol) {
    echo "<br><br>Student Discount: $" . $studentDiscount;
  }
  ?>

  <h3>Sales Tax:</h3> $<?php echo $salesTax; ?>

  <hr>

  <h3>Total Due on Delivery: </h3> $<?php echo $total; ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have two `<form>...</form>`. Use only one that has all the inputs inside it.

Comment: Yes, the submit button is in the second form so only that one is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have two forms in your HTML.

Refer to this part of your code:

```
...
    <form action="receipt.php" method="POST">
      <h2>HTech Pizzeria Online Order</h2>
      <fieldset>
          <legend><b>Customer Information</b></legend>
          Name: <input type="text" require id="customer" name="customer"
          placeholder="Enter Your Name..."><br>
          Phone Number: <input type="text" require id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber"
          placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number..."><br>
          Address: <input type="text" require id="address" name="address"
          placeholder="Enter Your Address..."><br>
      </fieldset>
  </div> 
  <form action="receipt.php" method="POST">
...
```

You're only submitting the second of the two forms and the customer info is in the first form.  Try consolidating your fields into one form and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps.